# Redis sorted set ordered by time with a score as well

Tags: lua, redis, leaderboard, sortedset

I'm trying to use a `Redis sorted set` with a score, sorted by time.

My current idea is to use a `Lua script` and `pack` the time and value in the score field, using `MessagePack` (`msgpack`).

- The time value is taken from `datetime.utcnow()` in Python that looks like this: `1417395600`.
- The score could have pretty much any kind of value.

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to pack those kind of values? Redis' sorted set seems to be limited to floats, unless I'm mistaken.
2. Would this keep the time order?

If you have any other idea for me on how to do this, please let me know. I would strongly prefer not to use another table just to store the score of each client...

PS: I actually do not care about the time, I simply need the scores (values) to be ordered by time, to use the sorted set as a leaderboard.

Comment: The score of Sorted Set members can only be used to store a floating point (IEEE 754) value.

Comment: Could I put the time, then a `.` (floating point) followed by the serialized score, to get a floating point number in a String, whatever my type of score?

Comment: Definitely, just mind the precision

Answer (score 2):

In a Redis sorted set when more than one element has the same score, the `ZRANGEBYSCORE` command returns elements in lexicographical order. So if you prefix you element with time, that should achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Using the property of sorted sets of sorting same score keys lexicographically. You can sort keys with any number of parameters like `first_score:second_score:third_score`.

Key here is the use of the **same padding** while creating a key with multiple scores.

> If A and B have exactly the same score, then A > B if the A string is lexicographically greater than the B string. A and B strings can't be equal since sorted sets only have unique elements.

In this example, I am using the same padding for all first scores and second scores while creating keys.

```
> zadd leaderboard 0 010:1234
> zadd leaderboard 0 009:1234
> zadd leaderboard 0 011:1234
> zadd leaderboard 0 010:2345
> zadd leaderboard 0 010:9999
> zrange leaderboard 0 -1 withscores
 1) "009:1234"
 2) "0"
 3) "010:1234"
 4) "0"
 5) "010:2345"
 6) "0"
 7) "010:9999"
 8) "0"
 9) "011:1234"
10) "0"
```